# g++ not working... need to change PATH variable

Tags: command-line, make, g++, paths

am working on Ubuntu machine. I have been trying to run make try to compile try.cpp. I am not able to make it work. I have tried all the solutions online. apt-get is what I am using. I have tried everything on the net.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and lot more.

It gives me the same problem again and again.

```
$ g++ try.cpp -o try
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [BHLDA] Error 127
```

I suspect that it is because my PATH variable is not proper. I dont know how to change my PATH variable in order to solve this problem. My PATH variable looks like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin
```

The priority selection of the package:

```
$ apt-cache policy g++
g++:
  Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
```

and

```
$ dpkg -L g++ | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the output of `which g++`?

Comment: it says nothing!!! that is another weird problem even after installing everything

Comment: Can you post the full results of `sudo apt-get install build-essential g++`? I'm assuming it gives you an error

Comment: no it says : `build-essential is already the newest version \n g++ is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.`

Comment: i tried `find /bin /usr -name g++` and got two results : `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/g++` and `/usr/share/doc/g++`

Comment: can you add the results of `apt-cache policy g++` and `dpkg -L g++ | grep bin` to the OP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19345/discussion-between-musher-and-mousecoder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussing with the OP in chat the output of `dpkg -L g++ | grep bin` was:

```
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
```

However, when OP did `file /usr/bin/g++` he got a file not found error.

I'm not sure which of the below fixed the issue, but something did:

First I had him try

```
sudo apt-get purge g++ 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
```

The first command removes build-essential, so it was necessary to reinstall it at the end. However, g++ still wasn't working as a command. Since the entry for `/usr/bin/g++` was still not there, I had him manually add in the symbolic link with

```
ln -sv /usr/bin/g++-4.8 /usr/bin/g++
```

And that seemed to solve the issue